# Endian conversion using boost

Tags: c++, boost, endianness

I followed the so called [manual of boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/endian/doc/choosing_approach.html) for converting (swapping) the endian.

Despite their [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/boost/endian/conversion.hpp) is more readable than their manual, could some one please explain how I should fix the following code?

hh.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/conversion.hpp>

int main () {

  std::cout << boost::endian::endian_reverse(5);

  return 0;
}
```

make:

```
g++ hh.cpp -o hh -Wall -Wconversion -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lrt  -lboost_wave -larmadillo -lboost_thread
```

error:

```
hh.cpp:3:39: fatal error: boost/endian/conversion.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/endian/conversion.hpp>
                                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

---

**Update**

Other boost headers are included fine. Only `endian` has problem.

```
ls /usr/include/boost/*
```

> http://pastebin.com/nCciracE

---

**Update**

```
$ cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
```

Result:

```
//  Boost version.hpp configuration header file  ------------------------------//

//  (C) Copyright John maddock 1999. Distributed under the Boost
//  Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file
//  LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

//  See http://www.boost.org/libs/config for documentation

#ifndef BOOST_VERSION_HPP
#define BOOST_VERSION_HPP

//
//  Caution, this is the only boost header that is guarenteed
//  to change with every boost release, including this header
//  will cause a recompile every time a new boost version is
//  released.
//
//  BOOST_VERSION % 100 is the patch level
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 is the minor version
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100000 is the major version

#define BOOST_VERSION 105400

//
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
//  but as a *string* in the form "x_y[_z]" where x is the major version
//  number, y is the minor version number, and z is the patch level if not 0.
//  This is used by <config/auto_link.hpp> to select which library version to link to.

#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_54"

#endif
```

Comment: Where are boost headers installed?

Comment: You clearly haven't set up the **boost root directory** aka `$BOOST_ROOT` in the [boost manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) and added it to your `INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: but other boost headers are ok: #include <boost/array.hpp>

Comment: @ar2015 okay, which version of boost you use? endian is new library.

Comment: @ForEveR Boost version: 0.19b.b8

Comment: @ar2015 open file boost/version.hpp and copy here value of macro BOOST_VERSION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endian` library was introduced in [boost version 1.58](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html).
You have 1.54, there is no `endian` library in this release. You should either update boost to 1.58+, either no use `endian` library.